# Missing or unsupported string?

Tags: android

While trying to run my app It says I'm missing or a string is unsupported this app worked before but when i added the class It suddenly wont run anymore Im pretty sure im missing something but im trying to find it for hours now I tried deleting it and doing the class again but it didnt work tried messing around with the build.gradle and changing its versions and revert it

Balance.class:

```
package com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

public class Balance extends AppCompatActivity{

private EditText AddBalanceView;
private EditText BalanceView;

    private EditText Balance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_balance);

        Balance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_editbalance);


        final Button signup_button = findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
        signup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Validating the log in data
                boolean validationError = false;

                StringBuilder validationErrorMessage = new StringBuilder("Please, insert ");
                if (isEmpty(Balance)) {
                    validationError = true;
                    validationErrorMessage.append("an balance");
                }
                validationErrorMessage.append(".");

                if (validationError) {
                    Toast.makeText(com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Balance.this, validationErrorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                //Setting up a progress dialog
                final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Balance.this);
                dlg.setTitle("Please, wait a moment.");
                dlg.setMessage("Signing up...");
                dlg.show();

                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(Balance.getText().toString());
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            dlg.dismiss();

                        } else {
                            dlg.dismiss();
                            ParseUser.logOut();
                            Toast.makeText(com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Balance.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(EditText text) {
        if (text.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean isMatching(EditText text1, EditText text2){
        if(text1.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString())){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    }
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Financial Management Assistant</string>
<string name="back4app_server_url">https://parseapi.back4app.com/</string>

<!-- Change the following strings as required -->
<string name="back4app_app_id">DtjIIdi90KoXKmpY8yjRSl76Aeq3NOlS3Svl5n6o</string>
<String name="balance">Balance</String>
<string name="username">Username</string>
<string name="email">Email</string>
<string name="back4app_client_key">nB4Gszy1bXhOe5iVvdgyFLRjzVK8temRVs2G7onQ</string>
<color name="Black">#000000</color>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
<string name="nav_header_title">Android Studio</string>
<string name="nav_header_subtitle">android.studio@android.com</string>
<string name="nav_header_desc">Navigation header</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
```

```
Error:

    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: C:\Users\Vermillon\Desktop\android-user-registration-master\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'String'
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:327)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: C:\Users\Vermillon\Desktop\android-user-registration-master\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'String'
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergingException.throwIfNonEmpty(MergingException.java:152)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:255)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:55)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:298)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Paste the error you are getting in your logcat.

Comment: I think it happened when I updated it but I dont know. it just might help me to solve the problem is there anyway to revert the update?

Comment: Please don’t post real project ids(back4app_app_id), use always fake information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<String name="balance">Balance</String>
```

to lower case `string`

```
<string name="balance">Balance</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove `<color name="Black">#000000</color>`  from string.xml and try to build the app.
**Updated** ::

`<String name="balance">Balance</String>`

make it

`<string name="balance">Balance</string>`

Comment: Nothing happen the problem just pop up again

Comment: @Euxicius have you clean and rebuilt the project?? Can you share your logcat error..

Comment: I tried clean and rebuild the project but same problem occur I also edit the errors

Answer (score 0):

Your resources declaration XML tags should always be in lower case.

So your

```
<String>
```

should actually be

```
<string>
```